# Display single record based from the URL (id)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a website where it displays all of my records. I can click on an individual record and it gets the `student_id` of that record and updates it to the URL eg. `view_student.php?id=12`.

It then takes me to a new page where I want it to display all the information about that record, in this case, show all information about student number 12, but none else.

I haven't a clue how to carry out the statement to display all of the information for that record, this is what I have so far:

```
if (isset($_GET['student_id'])) {
    echo $row['student_name'] . $row['student_age'] . $row['student_gender'];
}
```

This is a standalone page with nothing else on it. `view_student.php` simply uses a `require` function to this script. This code does not display anything, nor does it display any errors. I'm using PDO and I have made sure I'm connected to the database.

My guess is that I will need to use a `WHERE` clause but I'm just not too sure

Thank you

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a solved problem and any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) will have a routing layer that can break out these parameters for you and give you a proper Model-View-Controller structure to build on. If you're doing it as a stand-alone script that's all your responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below PDO query to fetch your data

```
    $statement = $db_con->prepare("select * from student where student_id = :student_id");
    $statement->execute(array(':student_id' => $_GET['student_id']));
    $row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```